# AWS ElasticBeanstalk in a production environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, production, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I wonder about the choice of AWS Elastic Beanstalk as an environment for the production system. Do you have some experience in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

More info as I have been using EB for more than 8 months...

So far so good, elastic beanstalk has its limitation though.

> 1. It is designed for service handling, but when you just want a processing unit, you need to do something additional for ELB and autoscaling.
> 2. Fixed in latest release: <strike>No VPC yet, so your Elastic Beanstalk is still exposed to the internet.</strike>, but VPC support is limited and need manually config through config files.
> 3. Fixed in latest release: <strike>Not easy to customize the webserver (e.g. tomcat) you have to use your own images</strike>.
> 4. Limited tuning option on the webserver parameter.
> 5. From my experience, reliability is OK not great, the main problem is the EB automation scripts sometime can stuck you environment.

But overall I like it.

Answer (score 2):

We deployed our Java webapplication (all three environments)  Beta, Staging and live on ElasticBeanStalk. They are doing well, so far we haven't faced any issues with Elastic Beanstalk.